# How can I center a ul with the dots on the left side in html?

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I want to center the ul in the center of the screen with all elements (li and the dots of ul) on the left side, but I couldn't do that

```css
ul {
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
  border: 3px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-size: 30px;
}

ul a li {
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <a href="">
    <li style="color: antiquewhite">item 1</li>
  </a>

  <a href="">
    <li style="color: antiquewhite">item 2</li>
  </a>

  <a href="">
    <li style="color: antiquewhite">item 3</li>
  </a>

  <a href="">
    <li style="color: antiquewhite">item 4</li>
  </a>
</ul>
```

Comment: Please put your code through a validator - it is not valid HTML to have an anchor element as the direct child of a ul.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained by A.Howarth in the comments, your markup is bad. `a` elements shouldn't be children of `ul` elements. That aside, if you want to put your `ul` in the middle then you can use `margin-inline: auto`. This is a fairly standard way of centering block level elements as explained in [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_align.asp) and [css tricks](https://css-tricks.com/centering-in-css/).

Divs will normally take up the full width of the viewport so you'd have to define a width for it (this could be in fixed units like `px` or `rem`, in percentages or even use `fit-content`)

In general if you're having problems centering elements then there's a handy tool called [howtocenterincss.com](http://howtocenterincss.com/).

Example below:

```css
ul {
  width: 50%; /* a div will automatically become full width unless you tell it otherwise */
  margin-inline: auto; /* margin-inline: auto will fill the space evenly on either side */
  border: 3px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-size: 30px;
}

ul li {
  color: antiquewhite;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="">item 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="">item 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="">item 3</a></li>
  <li><a href="">item 4</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: is there an alternative way to do this using only html , no css

Comment: Only if you used inline styles.